# Build inverted list of sentences and their respective positions in a document

Tags: python, inverted-index

I am attempting to build an inverted list of sentences and their position in the source document using Python and am failing miserably.

Let's say I have two documents:

**Doc1**

```
I like bananas. I don't like pears.
```

**Doc2**

```
I don't like heights. I like bananas.
```

I'm attempting to build an index of the sentences in these documents, that looks like this:

```
Sent                   File[pos]    
I like bananas         Doc1[1], Doc2[2]
I don't like pears     Doc1[2]
I don't like heights   Doc2[1]
```

I've found countless examples of building an inverted list of words and the files they can be found in, but can find nothing that deals with building an index of sentences.

I've tried hacking [a piece of code on Github](https://github.com/matteobertozzi/blog-code/blob/master/py-inverted-index/invindex.py) that deals with the traditional index of words, but I am clearly missing something because my hack doesn't work.

The code I'm using is set out below. The main difference in my code from the [code mentioned above](https://github.com/matteobertozzi/blog-code/blob/master/py-inverted-index/invindex.py) is that I'm using NLTK to tokenise the documents into sentences.

My code is as follows:

```
import nltk.data
import codecs
import os
import unicodedata


def sentence_split(text):
    sent_list = []
    scurrent = []
    sindex = None
    tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')

    for i, c in enumerate(text):
        if c.isalnum():
            scurrent.append(c)
            sindex = i

        elif scurrent:

            scurrent_str = ''.join(map(str, scurrent))
            sentence_prep = ''.join(tokenizer.tokenize(scurrent_str))

            sentence = ''.join(sentence_prep)
            sent_list.append((sindex - len(sentence) + 1, sentence))

    if scurrent:

        scurrent_str = ''.join(map(str, scurrent))
        sentence_prep = ''.join(tokenizer.tokenize(scurrent_str))
        sentence = ''.join(sentence_prep)
        sent_list.append((sindex - len(sentence) + 1, sentence))

    return sent_list

def sentence_normalize(sentences):
    normalized_sentences = []
    for index, sentence in sentences:
        snormalized = sentence.lower()
        normalized_sentences.append((index, snormalized))
    return normalized_sentences

def sentence_index(text):
    sentences = sentence_split(text)
    sentences = sentence_normalize(sentences)
    return sentences

def inverted_index(text):
    inverted = {}

    for index, sentence in sentence_index(text):
        locations = inverted.setdefault(sentence, [])
        locations.append(index)

    return inverted

def inverted_index_add(inverted, doc_id, doc_index):

    for sentence, locations in doc_index.items():
        indices = inverted.setdefault(sentence, {})
        indices[doc_id] = locations
    return inverted

def search(inverted, query):

    sentences = [sentence for _, sentence in sentence_index(query) if sentence in inverted]
    results = [set(inverted[sentence].keys()) for sentence in sentences]
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, results) if results else []

if __name__ == '__main__':
    doc1 = """
Niners head coach Mike Singletary will let Alex Smith remain his starting 
quarterback, but his vote of confidence is anything but a long-term mandate.
Smith now will work on a week-to-week basis, because Singletary has voided 
his year-long lease on the job.
"I think from this point on, you have to do what's best for the football team,"
Singletary said Monday, one day after threatening to bench Smith during a 
27-24 loss to the visiting Eagles.
"""

    doc2 = """
The fifth edition of West Coast Green, a conference focusing on "green" home 
innovations and products, rolled into San Francisco's Fort Mason last week 
intent, per usual, on making our living spaces more environmentally friendly 
- one used-tire house at a time.
To that end, there were presentations on topics such as water efficiency and 
the burgeoning future of Net Zero-rated buildings that consume no energy and 
produce no carbon emissions.
"""

    inverted = {}
    documents = {'doc1':doc1, 'doc2':doc2}
    for doc_id, text in documents.items():
        doc_index = inverted_index(text)
        inverted_index_add(inverted, doc_id, doc_index)

    for sentence, doc_locations in inverted.items():
        print (sentence, doc_locations)

    queries = ['I think from this point on, you have to do whats best for the football team,"Singletary said Monday, one day after threatening to bench Smith during a 27-24 loss to the visiting Eagles']
    for query in queries:
        result_docs = search(inverted, query)
        print("Search for '%s': %r" % (query, result_docs))
        for _, sentence in sentence_index(query):
            def extract_text(doc, index):
                return documents[doc][index:index+20].replace('\n', ' ')

            for doc in result_docs:
                for index in inverted[sentence][doc]:
                    print ('   - %s...' % extract_text(doc, index))

            print
```

Here's a snippet of the output:

```
niners {'doc1': [1]}
ninershead {'doc1': [2]}
ninersheadcoach {'doc1': [3]}
ninersheadcoachmike {'doc1': [4]}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
In [167]: txt1
Out[167]: "I like bananas. I don't like pears."

In [168]: txt2
Out[168]: "I don't like heights. I like bananas."

In [169]: doc1 = tokenizer.tokenize(txt1)
In [170]: doc2 = tokenizer.tokenize(txt2)

In [171]: sent_doc = [(sent, "doc" + str(idx+1) + str([idxx+1]))  for idx, it in enumerate([doc1, doc2]) for idxx, sent in enumerate(it)]

In [172]: sent_doc
Out[172]: 
[('I like bananas.', 'doc1[1]'),
 ("I don't like pears.", 'doc1[2]'),
 ("I don't like heights.", 'doc2[1]'),
 ('I like bananas.', 'doc2[2]')]
```

Now, construct the dictionary.

```
In [176]: dict_ = defaultdict()

In [177]: for sent, doc in sent_doc:
     ...:     if sent in dict_:
     ...:         dict_[sent] = dict_[sent] + [doc]
     ...:     else:
     ...:         dict_[sent] = [doc]

# output
In [178]: dict_
Out[178]: 
defaultdict(None,
            {"I don't like heights.": ['doc2[1]'],
             "I don't like pears.": ['doc1[2]'],
             'I like bananas.': ['doc1[1]', 'doc2[2]']})
```